# Python Mimetypes Missing application/ogg

Tags: python, mime-types

[Mimetypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mimetypes.html) says it supports registered [IANA mimetypes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), yet it does not seem to find the '.ogg' extension for the mimetype 'application/ogg'. I haven't checked to see what other mimetypes are missing, but perhaps the package registration is not kept up to date. Is there a way to make sure to sync mimetypes with the current list?

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mime_type = 'application/ogg'
>>> print(mimetypes.guess_extension(mime_type))
None
```

I'm using 3.5.2 on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mimetypes modules reads the system information about the file extension to mimetype and uses this.

The init function is used to intialize the default type map which is later used for all file types: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.init

So, for example, if in my system I map .ogv to application/ogg it will show that when using python's mimetype module. Even though it is not aguess_type() function (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type)

Comment: Interesting... not quite what I expected it to do but it's right there in the docs. Since none of the known files in the module seem to exist in a standard build of alpine or windows 8, I looked around for mime.types that support application/ogg (and other common type/sub-types) and found something here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.type then used the mimetypes.read_mime_types and mimetypes.add_type() to supplement the existing class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A better method in my experience is to use a more robust tool like exiftool or so. But that cannot be easily installed using pip. Hence I normally use mimetypes as a backup if exiftool is not installed and throw a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to exiftool. Looks very interesting... how would you say it compares to python-magic and libmagic?

Comment: If you're only looking for mimetypes, python-magic or libmagic are nice. Note that the python-magic in debian/fedora is not the same as python-magic in pypi (They have very different API). exiftool is majorly for media files and not meant for any generic mimetypes. But exiftool provides good additional meta information which was needed for my usecase.

Comment: If you do plan to use python-magic here's a snippet I had written to support both python-magic in pypi and debian - https://github.com/pywikibot-catfiles/file-metadata/blob/master/file_metadata/generic_file.py#L171